# Where is CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY and PROVISIONING_PROFILE parameters in xcodebuild documented?

Tags: xcode

When I use xcodebuild like so:

```
xcodebuild archive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$codeSignIdentity" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="$provision_UUID"
```

I am confused about the PROVISIONING_PROFILE and CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY parameters.
My app has both iOS and Apple Watch targets. How do I config these parameters? Where are the documents about that?